# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Sastrawi'

Tags: text

I've been looking for a solution to this problem, they said just install Sastrawi module with `pip install Sastrawi` , but after I installed the module, the error still doesn't go away.

what do i need to do?

Comment: Are you using PyCharm IDE? If yes, install the module using the IDE. If you install it using the command line, it may not be visible in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own problem

So, for the problem I've had, I previously installed the literary library on the laptop's CMD.... I should have installed it in jupyter itself, not on the laptop's CMD.